# How in Matlab do changes on figure 1 with slider on figure 2?

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-guide, figure

I have some sliders on figure 1, and I have some images on figure 2. I want to do the *callbacks* for the sliders in a way that, when I change the sliders in *figure 1* , the threshold changes and images update automatically in *figure 2*.

I'm using `addlistener` to send values for callback function. The problem is when you move slider the *active figure is figure 1*, and you want to do changes on figure 2.

adding some code for clarification:

```
M.rgbImage = imread('euhedral-mag-on-po-edge-pseudo-sub-ophitic-rl-fov-4-8mm.jpg');
[rows, columns, numberOfColorBands] = size(M.rgbImage);
F.f = figure;   % This is the figure which has the axes to be controlled.

% Now create the other GUI
S.fh = figure('units','pixels',...
              'position',[400 400 500 100],...
              'menubar','none',...
              'name','Image control',...
              'numbertitle','off',...
              'resize','off');

S.sl = uicontrol('style','slide',...
    'unit','pix',...
    'position',[60 10 270 20],...
    'min',0,'max',255,'val',100,...
    'callback',{@sl_call2,S},'deletefcn',{@delete,F.f});
```

....

```
lis = addlistener(S.sl,'Value','PostSet',@(e,h) sl_call3(S,F,M)); 


function sl_call3(S,F,M)
v = get(S.sl,'value');
figure(F.f), subplot(4, 4, 13);
M.redMask = (M.redPlane > v);
imshow(M.redObjectsMask, []);
set(S.ed(2),'string',v);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create reference to both your figures:

```
f1=figure(1);
f2=figure(2);
```

And then when doing the callback pass f2 as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In the callback, you'll have get the handle to the second figure.
There's various ways to do that.

You can specify the handle to the second figure at the time of callback-definition:

```
figure2 = ...;
addlistener(hSlider, ..., @(a,b) changeStuffOn(figure2));
```

Or during the callback:

```
function callbackFunction(hObject, evt)
    % get the handle to the second figure, e.g. by a tag, or its name
    fig2 = findobj(0, 'type', 'figure', 'tag', 'figure2'); % 

    % do whatever you want with fig2
end
```

The latter might be somewhat worse in performance, but e.g. has the benefit of working reliably even if figure2 was deleted and recreated and some point.

To avoid the change of focus you'll have to get rid of this line your callback:

```
figure(F.f)
```

This explicitly moves the focus to the second figure.
You'll have to use e.g. the `imshow(axes_handle, ...)` syntax, in order to show the image not in the "current axes".

Comment: I tried this, the problem is when you touch the slider in figure 1, the active figure changes to figure 2 by this function, and you can't move slider anymore.

Comment: so in the end of the callback function (or the propmts of figure2), just declare again `figure (1)`, so it'll become the active one back

Comment: In that way the figure 1 keeps disappear and appear again and again by each slider movement.